# ASP.NET MVC form won't submit in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have an issue submitting a form using internet explorer or edge. The form submits fine in both Chrome and Firefox. The problem appears to be coming from the OpenIdConnect authorisation flow but I'm struggling to isolate it, especially as it works with other browsers.

The application uses Azure AD to authenticate.

So, here is the html:

```html
<div class="form form-horizontal form-validate block block-size-a auto-form-submit">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="control-group control-group-odd">
            <div class="control-label">
                <label for="searchText">Search</label>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="Names and Emails" name="searchText" value="@Model.SearchText">
            </div>
        </div>
        if (ViewBag.UserIsSA)
        {
            <div class="control-group control-group-odd">
                <div class="control-label">
                    <label for="clientId">Client</label>
                </div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="input-xlarge auto-form-submit-select" name="clientId">
                        <option value="0">Show all</option>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Clients)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.Id" @(item.Id == Model.SelectedClientId ? "selected" : "")>@item.Name (@item.ClientNumber)</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="control-group control-group-odd">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-alt btn-style-e">Filter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

This is the method that the form submits to:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string searchText = "", int clientId = 0, int page = 1, int pageSize = 10)
            {
...
    }
```

I've checked the request and the correct values appear to be set but it never gets as far as hitting the method in IE

and this is the error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: parameter    Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: parameter
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   parameter]
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.AuthenticationProtocolMessage.SetParameter(String
>   parameter, String value) +138
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectMessage..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters) +124
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.d__1a.MoveNext()
>   +1063    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.d__34.MoveNext()
>   +154    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +383
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext()
>   +187    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +561
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext()
>   +187    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__2.MoveNext()
>   +185    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +69
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +64
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +380    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

For completeness, as I think it may be relevant, here is the code from my Startup.Auth.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Tour")
            });


            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        //
                        // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                        //

                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;

                            // Create a Client Credential Using an Application Key
                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(
                                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
                            AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                                code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);
                            AuthenticationHelper.token = result.AccessToken;
                        }

                    }
                });
        }
```

So, it looks as though a null value is being passed to

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.AuthenticationProtocolMessage.SetParameter(String parameter, String value)
```

but where is it coming from and why do I not have the issue in non-microsoft browsers?

**EDIT:**
This is happening all over the application whenever I try to post form data to an action.

Any help appreciated

Comment: What does the method you're trying to POST to look like? The exception you listed has a message about "Description" being required. I don't see that in your authorization code. Your problem sounds more like a disabled input not being sent over.

Comment: Thanks for looking @krillgar. I've edited to include the method underneath the html section now.

Comment: can you post the `<authentication>` section of your web.config?

Comment: Since the problem is only in Edge and IE: I have experienced problems with mixing trusted and untrusted sites. E.g. if your website is in IE's Trusted Sites list, and login.microsoftonline.com is not, then you may have authentication problems.

Comment: Failed to reproduce this issue, were you developing with the latest version of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect`? Or if it is possible to share a code demo to help to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @JamieD77 I do not have an authentication section in web.config. It's based on this sample here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect which doesn't have one either

Comment: @RasmusW Gah! Damn the company policy that won't let me edit my trusted sites! I'll get that sorted and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT I do have the latest version, 3.1 installed. How would I go about sharing a code demo?

Comment: You can the code sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/) and please don't forget remove the sensitive information before you publish it.

Comment: I've realised that this is happening on all form posts and only form posts if that helps at all?

Comment: Finally found a solution to this though none the wiser as to why the issue was browser specific. It seems you MUST specify a value for the RedirectUri option within OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions for form posts to work in IE/Edge!

Comment: You should make this an answer and get credit for yourself. I had the same problem, but using ADFS instead of OpenID. Configuring the Wreply addressed this issue.